# Set property overlay dynamically - CustomBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript-objects

I am using `Custombox` for modals. I have a button and when it is clicked the modal is open:

```
    var regModal = new Custombox.modal({
    content: {
        effect: 'fadein',
        target: '#reg',
        container: "#target",
    },
    overlay:{
        close: true
    }

});

$('#regBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    regModal.open();
});
```

This modal has another button. I want when this button is clicked to prevent or no closing modal on overlay click. The property for this is :

```
regModal.options.overlay.close
```

The problem is that when I set it to false (no close modal on overlay click) like this:

```
regModal.options.overlay.close = false
```

, it is no apply to the current modal, but to next modal after I close the current.
Is there way dynamically change `overlay.close` property ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this :

```
$('#regOtherBtn').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    regModal.options.overlay.close = false
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I do, but it will be applied for the next modal, but not the current modal.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to bind a click event to overlay with custom logic for closing the modal or not :

```
var regModal = new Custombox.modal({
    content: {
        effect: 'fadein',
        target: '#reg',
        container: "#target",
    },
    overlay:{
        close: false // Do not close on overlay click
    }

});
var closeOnClick = false;
$('#modalBtn').click(function(e){
    closeOnClick = true;
});
// Bind a click event to overlay
$('body').on('click', '.custombox-content', function (e) {
    // If overlay is clicked and closeOnClick is true. close the modal
    if($(e.target).hasClass('custombox-content') && closeOnClick ){
        Custombox.modal.close();
    }
});
```